# ReBind Telerik RadGrid from RadToolBarButton +AJAX

Tags: c#, ajax, user-controls, telerik, radgrid

I've been using Telerik Controls for a couple months now, and have yet to apply AJAX to any of my UserControls. While I've been learning, I've been doing full Postback's every time I need to Update a RadGrid or insert data. After getting my Web App looking the way I want it, I've realized that doing full Postback's not only looks bad, but it is quite slow.

At the moment all I am looking to do is ReBind a RadGrid using a refresh button on a RadToolBar. I am sure that once I grasp this, I will be able to apply AJAX to other places on my page.

I am currently running a Master Page, which consists of my Main Page, and my Main Page holds a RadTabStrip linked to a few other UserControls.

Does anyone know of any good (**basic**) tutorials that will aid me in learning AJAX with Telerik, as I am unfamiliar with both AJAX and Java, but am open to learning...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently run up into series of blog posts about AJAX and telerik ajax on their blogs - you can read them [here](http://blogs.telerik.com/toddanglin/posts/07-03-08/the_ajax_papers_part_i.aspx). Also I know about a demo that does what you are asking for - toolbar incorporated into grid's command item, [check it out](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/toolbar/examples/applicationscenarios/gridcommanditem/defaultcs.aspx?product=grid).